# sqoop job works in command promp but not hue workflow

Tags: hadoop, oozie, hue, sqoop

I have the following sqoop import which works fine from command line.

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:db2://<location> --username <username>--password-file <pwfillocation> --table tableName --where "column=1" --split-by columnName --incremental append -check-column LST_UPDTD_TS -hive-import --hive-database dbName --hive-table hiveTableName --target-dir <targetDirLoc>
```

However, when I put this into a sqoop action within a hue workflow it fails on the hive-import command.  If I take that part out then it runs fine in hive as well.

The error message is not very useful:

```
67693 [main] INFO  org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport  - Loading uploaded data into Hive
Intercepting System.exit(1)
<<< Invocation of Main class completed <<<

Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain], exit code [1]

Oozie Launcher failed, finishing Hadoop job gracefully
```

I've seen a few other similar questions, but haven't been able to find a concreate answer that works.  Any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: Could you add job logs

Comment: can you add a scoop action code ?